# Problems with glossaries in Texmaker?

Tags: glossaries, texmaker

I'm kind of new to LaTeX and I'm struggling a lot to make a glossary. I'm using Texmaker under Windows, but I'm not very good at programing. I'm using `\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}` because I read that there is no version of `xindy` (somehow better for spanish users as myself) for Windows, or the solutions I found where rather hard for me to understand. 
I wrote the `\makeglossaries` and `\printglossaries` commands, and I made the user command `makeglossaries`.

On of my entries looks like this:

```
\newglossaryentry{inconel}
{name = inconel,
description = {Familia ... Special Metals Corporation.} }
```

There seems to be no errors in the documents as I can compile the document, but when I hit the makeglossaries user command, I get this error:

> ***Call to makeindex failed*** Possible cause of problem: Style name indicates makeindex, but may be in xindy format. Remember to use `\setStyleFile` to specify the name of the style file rather than redefining \istfilename explicitly. Check 'Documento maestro.glg' for details

(`Documento maestro` is the name of my main file.)

What am I doing wrong?

I know that the question may be very basic but I need to do this for my graduate thesis and I'm finding a big wall with this.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Having spaces in file names is often a sure way to have problems. Try renaming your files so that they have no space

Comment: It was just the space in the name! That worked, the glossary is now working! Thanks!

Comment: @ariblogger Please don’t create crossposts in several forums without explicitly acknowledging that you’re doing so. http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=23029

Answer (score 6):

Spaces in file names are usually a good source for headaches.

Always use file names without spaces in connection with TeX and friends.